# What is the value of $ \sum_{n=1}^{9999}\big [ \dfrac {1} {n^{\frac{1}{4}}}\big ]$ where $[.] $ is the greatest integer function.

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

What is the value of $  \sum_{n=1}^{9999} \big [ \dfrac {1} {n^{\frac{1}{4}}}\big  ]$ where $[\cdot] $ is the greatest integer function.

I do not seem to possess any clue about this problem. Any hints will be deeply appreciated please.

Thank you!

Comment: Stated in current form, the sum is $1$. This is because for $n > 1$, $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}} \in (0,1)$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Are you sure you have placed the $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ correctly? I suspect the floor function should be applied only to the denominator instead of the whole fraction...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mh, what about

$$1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+\cdots 0\ ?$$

---

If the question is in fact

$$\sum_{1}^{9999}\frac1{\lfloor \sqrt[4]n\rfloor},$$

consider that there are

- $15$ terms (from $1$ to $15$) equal to $1$,
- $65$ terms (from $16$ to $80$) equal to $\dfrac12$,
- $175$ terms (from $81$ to $255$) equal to $\dfrac13$,
- $\cdots$
- $3439$ terms (from $6561$ to $9999$) equal to $\dfrac19$.